# Is $\{x\mid\frac{x}{2} \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ not a valid representation of multiples of two?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my pre-calculus class, I suggested $\{x\mid\frac{x}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ as set-builder notation for multiples of two. I was told that is not correct, with the correct answer being $\{x\mid 2n=x, x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. To my understanding, the conditionals simply need to be true in order for a number to be contained in the set, and all multiples of two satisfy the conditionals in my notation. Why is is that my answer is incorrect?

I apologize for my lack of vocabulary, I have only been introduced this concept less than a week ago.

Comment: I would even say that $\{ x\,|\, 2n=x, x\in \mathbb Z\}$ is not correct since it has an unquantified variable $n$.  It should be $\{x\,|\, \text{there is an}\, n\in\mathbb Z\, \text{such that}\, x=2n\}$.

Comment: @AustinMohr $\frac{2}{2}=1, 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @ZebMcCorkle I think you meant $\{x | 2n = x, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is the correct notation.

Comment: By the way, I like your set builder notation just fine.

Comment: Is it $\{x\mid\frac{x}{2}\in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ or $\{x\mid\frac{x}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?  Those are two different sets since $\mathbb{N}$ is just the positive integers (and sometimes $0$).

Comment: -2 is a multiple of two, so you'll want to use $\mathbf{Z}$ in your definition.

Comment: There are two problems with yours both "style points" that do not make yours wrong as yours is right.  1) the x in Z isn't nesc; x/2 in Z forces it to happen.  2) You don't directly convey the concept "x is 2 times some integer" but instead "x divided by 2 results in an integer" as this concepts are *equivalent* no-one can claim one is right and the other isn't.  But for clarity, aesthetics, straightforwardness, I'd prefer {x|x=2y; y \in Z} .... tbc...

Comment: Meanwhile {x| x = 2n; x in Z} *is* wrong.  It implies n has be a defined single value and the set is simply {2n}, a set with on single element.

Comment: Actually my favorite would be just {2n|n in Z}.  But yours is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is either yours or $\{x|x=2n,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ The one you said was the "answer" from the book is not right. For one thing, there is an extra $n$ floating around on the right side which isn't bound by a quantifier.

Actually if spelled out a bit more with a quantifier the book answer also works:
$$\{x | (\exists n \in Z) \ x=2n \}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I would say that if we're working strictly over $\Bbb N$ (or $\Bbb Z$) then it's not correct because $\frac x2$ is not defined for all $x\in \Bbb N$ (or $\Bbb Z$).  Otherwise your notation is fine.

Comment: The "universe" is ambiguous in both cases.  It is not stated anywhere that $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.  It could be that the universe is $\mathbb{Q}$...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer should be $\{ x\in \Bbb Z\mid \exists n\in\Bbb Z: 2n=x\}$ in the most complete form.

However, $\{x\mid \frac x 2\in\Bbb Z, x\in\Bbb Z\}$ is quite *okay*.   It sais what you want to say and is reasonably concise.

Still I'd point out that $~\{2x\in\Bbb Z\mid x\in \Bbb Z\}~$, or even just $~\{ 2x\mid x\in \Bbb Z\}~$, is a bit *clearer*.   It is compact yet gets right to the point.

Comment: I'd also point out x/2 in Z; x in Z is redundant.  But it isn't wrong.  (The book is though.)